# How to speed up LinearModelFit, or use an alternative, for repeated use

Tags: performance-tuning, fitting

I would like to implement a LOESS regression in Mathematica. My implementation depends on `LinearModelFit`, which is too slow to use on large datasets. (Can't use `Fit` because we need weights). Here is my current version:

```
loess[data_, order_, smoothing_] :=
 Module[{d, weights, filtered, fData, fWeights, fit, x, weight, funcs},
  weight[z_] := Piecewise[{{(1 - Abs[z]^3)^3, Abs[z] < 1}}];
  funcs = Table[x^i, {i, 0, order}];
  Table[
   d = (data[[;; , 1]] - point[[1]])/smoothing;
   weights = weight /@ d;
   filtered = 
    Cases[Transpose[Join[Transpose[data], {weights}]], 
     a_ /; a[[3]] != 0];
   fData = filtered[[;; , {1, 2}]];
   fWeights = filtered[[;; , 3]];
   fit = LinearModelFit[fData, funcs, x, Weights -> fWeights]
   {point[[1]], fit[point[[1]]]}
   , {point, data}]
  ]
```

With an example dataset:

```
data = Table[{x, 2*x^3 - 1.5 x^2 + RandomReal[{-0.05, 0.05}]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.001}];
```

running `loess[data, 2, 0.1]` takes about 7 seconds on my machine.

Is there a way to speed up this function? The accepted answer will also allow access to the slope of the LOESS regression; for example by returning `{point[[1]], fit'[point[[1]]]}` in the above implementation.

(Note that my definition of the smoothing parameter is non-standard.)

Comment: I don't feel it's satisfying, but: Replacing LinearModelFit with NonlinearModelFit reduces the computation time on my machine from 13s to 9s.

Comment: Reading your motivation for implementing LOESS regression, are you interested in any other algorithms to be applied that would be fast enough?

Comment: I would certainly be interested in a completely different implementation of LOESS, if it were faster. Is that what you had in mind? If not, still curious what you are thinking of.

Comment: If `Fit` works faster, you can simply use `data * weights` instead of `data` for weighted fit.

Comment: You went to the trouble of creating `filtered`, `fData` and `fWeights` but then used `data` and `weights` in the fitting process. Typo?  I get the same answer with both approaches with a factor of two speedup using the  `fData` and `fWeights`. This would become more significant the larger the data set.

Comment: Thanks Jack, I have updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

As per discussion in the comments, here is an answer using [Quantile Regression](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2014/01/01/quantile-regression-with-b-splines/) that produces a fitted curve for less than 0.5 seconds on my computer. (The function `loess` in the question took 8 seconds.)

Generate the data (as in the question):

```
data = Table[{x, 2*x^3 - 1.5 x^2 + RandomReal[{-0.05, 0.05}]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.001}];
```

Load the QuantileRegression.m package:

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/QuantileRegression.m"]
```

Do quantile regression with 12 B-spline basis nodes for the quantile 0.5:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 qfunc = QuantileRegression[data, 12, {0.5}][[1]];
]

(* {0.343834, Null} *)
```

Plot the data and the regression quantile curve:

```
ListPlot[{data, {#, qfunc[#]} & /@ data[[All, 1]]}]
```

[image]